# Pipeline dump and load from s3 for predict

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pickle

Im creating a pipeline:

```
estimator = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=18,n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1)

mapper = DataFrameMapper([(i, None) if j != 'object' and j != 'bool' else (i, LabelEncoder()) for i, j in
                                  zip(train_x.columns.values, train_x.dtypes.values)]
                                 , input_df=True, df_out=True)



pipeline = Pipeline([("mapper", mapper),
                   ("classifier", estimator)])


pipeline.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

I want to be able to load it to s3 and then load it for predict. 
I understand how can I do it locally:

```
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'filename.pkl') 
pkl_file = joblib.load('filename.pkl') 
prediction = pkl_file.predict(train_x)
```

But how can I dump the pickle to s3 and load it from s3 ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to load the file into s3:

```
import joblib
import boto3 
import tempfile

bucket = 'your bucket name here'
key = 'your key name here'
model = your_model_object

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
    joblib.dump(model_name, tmp)
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=tmp.read())
```